# PHP If date is x and time is greater than x pm show A else if show B

Tags: php, wordpress, date, if-statement, time

I am trying to tell a wordpress feature to display a post date based on some complicated factors (conditions)

I have to show an advent style of posts. Everyday starting Dec 1, a new post will be placed at this position of the site. But the catch is the posts are different for Canada (all), Canada (BC) and USA. So here is what I essentially want it to do

Timezone : Edmonton

```
                            If date is from dec 1 5:00pm to dec 2 4:59pm {
                            if the user is in BC 
                            {show postid 1 
                            }else if the user is in USA
                            {show postid 2
                            }else{
                            show postid 3
                            }
                            }else
                            if date is from dec 2 5:00pm to dec 3 4:59pm{
                            if the user is in BC 
                            {show postid 4 
                            }else if the user is in USA
                            {show postid 5
                            }else{
                            show postid 6
                            }
                            }else.....
                            so on for 25 days (till December 25th)
```

I have been able to get most of what I want but I was not able to add the time factor since I do not know enough in php 
right now my code only displays if the date is as set & based on the ip.

```
                            function showheroslider(){
                            date_default_timezone_set("America/Edmonton"); 

                            if (date('F, j, Y') == 'December, 1, 2016' ){

                            $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
                            if ($userInfo->mostSpecificSubdivision->name == 'British Columbia'){ 

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1123);

                            } else if ($userInfo->country->name == 'United States'){

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1123);

                            } else {

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1123);

                            }
                            } else 
                            if (date('F, j, Y') == 'December, 2, 2016' ){

                            $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
                            if ($userInfo->mostSpecificSubdivision->name == 'British Columbia'){ 

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1097);

                            } else if ($userInfo->country->name == 'United States'){

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1097);

                            } else {

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1097);

                            }
                            } else
                            if (date('F, j, Y') == 'December, 3, 2016' ){

                            $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
                            if ($userInfo->mostSpecificSubdivision->name == 'British Columbia'){ 

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1206);

                            } else if ($userInfo->country->name == 'United States'){

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1204);

                            } else {

                            $adventdatepost = get_post(1206);

                            }else .......
```

To summarize the issue is : 
1. Instead of Just on the date, I need it to display based on date and time 
2. If this is not too complicated I want to actually be able to edit this to work on days of every month instead of just for December. (Meaning 1st day of the month 5pm to 2nd day of the month 4:59pm show this else ..)

Point 1 is of priority. Please help me as I have tried my best to come this far. But I do not know how to tackle the time issue.

Comment: don't use strings, you're just making it harder to compare date and time, either use unix timestamps or utilize `DateTime` classes instead, then you have checks in between

Comment: @Ghost yes but that will specify to only december - what if I wanted this to be for every month based on the day of the month and between 5:00pm to next day 4:59pm?

Comment: it doesn't matter what month it is, surely `DateTime` can handle that criteria

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. 
I am still not 100% sure but I think this can work

```
if((date('j') == 25 && date('G') >= 17) || (date('j') == 26 && date('G') < 17)){ 
$adventdatepost = get_post('insert id for day 25);
}
else 
{
$adventdatepost = get_post('insert id for the post I want till 30 or 31st');
}
```

This tells it if the day of the month is 1 and time is greater than 5pm or if the date is 2 and time is less than 5pm ... show post for day 1

so on and so forth till 25 days. and then after day 25 it can post the specific post until the next 1 day of the month.